# View referrals from one part of my site to another in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, referrer, path

I have an online shop with a blog structured this way:

- Shop: `example.com`
- Blog: `example.com/blog`

Both index have the same Google Analytic Code (UA).
In the blog I write articles about some products with a link to the product page.

Now the problem is, I want to see stat on visits whose referral links have this pattern `example.com/blog/*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Click Behavior/Behavior Flow** for a graphical view with *many* options. Above the chart, for example, there is a pulldown menu that defaults to "Automatically Grouped Pages," but you might want to experiment with the other options to get a view that shows exactly what you want.

**Click Behavior/Site Content/All Pages, then click the tab "Navigation Summary"**, for a different perspective that also has many options.

There are many things in the Behavior section, and the above two are merely the tip of the iceberg.